# .htaccess rewrite rule with a fake directory with a parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I was wondering how can I make it where I have a directory for say domain.com/main/ and in that /main I have license.php with .htaccess how am I able to make it where I can do domain.com/main/view/license/(license) and it shows them domain.com/license.php?id={license} ive tried this and it doesn't work

This is my current .htaccess that I use that im trying to make it work with

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^/view/license/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ license.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this rule in either a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file) in the http server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder, or, preferably, in the real host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?main/view/license/?$ /license.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?main/view/license/([^/]+)/?$ /license.php?id=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Sorry if you saw my last comment but now after trying it, it says Error 404 if I do ```/view/license``` but it doesn't show it if I do ```/view/license/583498``` I want it to still go to the license.php page if the variable is not defined.

Comment: A added a second, more specific rewriting rule for that specific case. That is a clean solution in my eyes.

Comment: It certainly does, why not? Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteRule ^main/view/license/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ license.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Adding `main` to the rule, and removing the first slash.